# Forever Crashes and Doesn't Restart after 4 times

Tags: node.js, forever

I have a node server running on AWS and I am using forever to keep it running in the background.

I have been very happy with forever so far; it's super easy to set up and use. However, even though my app is very simple, sometimes it crashes with this error:

```
Express server listening on port 3001

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
error: Forever restarting script for 4 time
```

When I look back at the logs, I can see that this has happened 4 more times, and each time forever manages to restart the server. However, when it happens for the 5th time, for some reason forever fails to restart the server and my app becomes unresponsive.

```
Express server listening on port 3001

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8

/usr/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/forever-monitor/node_modules/broadway/node_modules/eventemitter2/lib/ev$
          throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                         ^
Error: Cannot stop process that is not running.
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/forever-monitor/lib/forever-monitor/monitor.js:332:26
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Has anyone else experienced similar problems?

Comment: you could also, say, fix the bug you have that keeps crashing the server.

Comment: also, nginx is not really related to forever at all.  It's just a fronting proxy.

Comment: You have a bug somewhere in your http or net application, and this bug crashes your app. Fix it and it will run again as suppose to. It is nothing to do with forever.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the option `-MAX` like this:

```
forever -MAX 10000000000 Mypath/ToMyFile.js
```

Also put a `-minUptime` for the minimum time the server can stay up, if it crash before that laps of time then it won't go up again so set it to 1.

```
forever --minUptime (number-in-milisecond-here) -MAX (number-of-restart-here) path/file.js
```

Just try this:

```
forever --minUptime 1 -MAX 1000000000 YourPath/ToYourFile.js
```

More documentation there
https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Answer (score 0):

To allow a max of 100 restarts when the server crashes

```
forever start -m 100 index.js
```